# Troubleshooting "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string" when echoing result of get_browser()

Tags: php, echo

```
<?
/*current browser*/
$string = get_browser("name");
echo("$string");
?>
```

is giving me the error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\endlessdescription\header.php on line 106

line 106 is `echo("$string")`. I have a similar bit of code that displays the last modified date/time above and it works fine.

I pulled this from a book so I don't see why it wouldn't work, is "name" not a valid argument of `get_browser`? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you ever use `"$string"` instead of `$string`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php), from the official documentation, the function `get_browser` return an array, not just a string. So you have to choose the info you need and print it accordingly.
Maybe the best info that fits your need is to echo the value of `browser`.

Answer (score 1):

try something like:

```
<?
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
echo($browser['browser']);
?>
```

Comment: this displays "default browser", which is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

As the dude above said, it returns in array, a way to print this out is using foreach();
This prints out the array.

```
foreach($string as $string => $sub)
{
    echo $string.'<br />'.$sub.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: Using the name of the initial array as the variable for the key is extremely ugly and maybe even likely to cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

From the [get_browser documentation](http://php.net/get_browser) on php.net:

> In order for this to work, your browscap configuration setting in
>   php.ini must point to the correct location of the browscap.ini file on
>   your system.  browscap.ini is not bundled with PHP, but you may find
>   an up-to-date php_browscap.ini file
>   [here](http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads.asp).